# SwiftUI and Picker and FireStore return doc ID not fall

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, swiftui-picker

I have two DisclosureGroup with a picker in each.  The first picker is just reading from a static array of years and works without issue.  The second picker which populates the picker the user names but when you select a user the value is the Firebase doc id, not the fullname value.

```
// MARK: - DISCLOSER GROUP TRIP YEAR
   DisclosureGroup("Trip Year: \(String(selectedYear))", isExpanded: $tripYearIsExpanded) {
      Picker(selection: $selectedYear, label: Text("")) {
         ForEach(years, id: \.self) {
            Text(String($0))
         } // END:FOREACH
      } // END:PICKER
     .onChange(of: selectedYear, perform: { value in
        getTrips(passedYear: selectedYear)
      })
    } // END:DISCLOSUREGROUP
     .padding(.horizontal)
                
    // MARK: - DISCLOSURE GROUP DRIVER
    DisclosureGroup("Driver: \(selectedDriver)", isExpanded: $driverIsExpanded) {
      Picker(selection: $selectedDriver, label: Text("")) {
         ForEach(userListVM.userVM, id: \.id) { user in
            Text(user.fullname)
         } // END:FOREACH
      } // END:PICKER
        .onChange(of: selectedDriver, perform: { value in
           print("SELECTED DRIVER: \(selectedDriver)")
        })
      }
      .padding(.horizontal)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted `selectedDriver` to be the name, you *could* change your `ForEach` to be based on `fullname` instead of `id`:

```
ForEach(userListVM.userVM, id: \.fullname) {
```

However, if you ever had the occasion where two drivers had the same name, this would have funny results.

Perhaps a better option would be deriving the model back from the selected ID:

*in `onChange`*:

```
print("SELECTED DRIVER ID: \(selectedDriver)")
let selectedDriverModel = userListVM.userVM.first { $0.id == selectedDriver }
print("Selected driver name: \(selectedDriverModel?.fullname ?? "")")
```

Comment: I know it is frowned upon, but thanks for the suggestion.